# Print a different view as the current one in Infopath GUI, using C# in the VSTA environment

Tags: c#, .net, infopath, vsta

I'm developing a GUI for Infopath. 
I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications with C# as
developing language. 
I have two views in my project, one is the result of the other. I'm getting
problem with print button (as PDF):
 I'm trying to print the resulting view (modified over the first) from the editing
 one. What I got until now is a code that prints the current view.
How can I print the second one !

```
public void PrintBtn_Clicked(object sender, ClickedEventArgs e)
    {
         this.CurrentView.Export("TestFileName.pdf", ExportFormat.Pdf);
    }
```

Thanks.
Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the Export method is only available on a View object and unfortunately InfoPath des not expose a view collection for you. I think your best bet would probably be to switch to the view you want to print via

```
ViewInfos.SwitchView("view name");
```

Then you can do your call to export. Then finally you can switch back to the previous view if required...

I would expect this to flick up the second view for the user for a moment while the export is taking place but I can't test it because I'm in an an airport :p

Comment: That is exactly my actual approach ! I hoped that someone maybe has some trickier way !
Thank you for your confirmation ... I will tag your answer as accepted !